# How to use bucket sort to sort a set of strings

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, bucket-sort

I have a set of strings say Set `S` = `{string1, string2 ... upto N }`. I need to sort them lexicographically.

**How to use bucket sort to do so ?**

Also tell any other efficient method that can be used to solve the question.

Comment: What's wrong with [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)? Also, you should know by now that this isn't the place to ask people to just give you code.

Comment: @juanchopanza i meant to say that i have some n no of strings.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, if the length of each string is also n, it would be n^2log(n) (nlog(n) comparisons and O(n) for comparing two different strings.) I need to do it in nlogn(n).

Comment: @Ninja420 Comparing strings is theoretically O(n), but in practice, the multiplier will be very small, since the comparison only has to go to the first position where the characters are not equal.  (And if the strings all have the same prefix, they'll all end up in the same bucket, and using bucket sort won't buy you anything.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort by the first character.  This gives you some number of "buckets."  Sort each nonempty bucket starting with the second character.  Repeat until the whole thing is sorted.